# android studio render erros

Tags: android, xml, rendering, render

I got a rendering problem with the app and I don't have any information about it, I even rewrite the code, it still gives this error, can you help me:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed   at android.graphics.Canvas.checkValidClipOp(Canvas.java:853)   at android.graphics.Canvas.clipPath(Canvas.java:1081)   at com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingMenuLayout.dispatchDraw(FlowingMenuLayout.java:109)   at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21446)   at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21417)   at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21317)   at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)   at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)   at com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.BuildLayerFrameLayout.dispatchDraw(BuildLayerFrameLayout.java:81)   at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21446)   at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21417)   at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21317)   at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)   at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)   at com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.ElasticDrawer.dispatchDraw(ElasticDrawer.java:775)   at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21446)   at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21417)   at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21317)   at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)   at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)   at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21315)   at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)   at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)   at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21315)   at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)   at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)   at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21446)   at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21417) 
Copy stack to clipboard   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.`

This is the my xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingDrawer
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:night="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:edPosition="2"
    app:edMenuSize="260dp"
    app:edMenuBackground="#dddddd">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/nephritis"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            >
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="end">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_night"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/moon_icon"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:onClick="set_night"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txt_text"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_text"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/bold"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/giahan"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img_icon"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_night"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

                    night:night_textColor="#180101" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_icon"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:gravity="center">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_main"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_profile123456"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="12sp"/>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_fehrest"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:textAllCaps = "false"
                    android:text="@string/listmozo"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/medium"
                    android:onClick="fehrest_intent"
                    android:background="@drawable/back_btn4"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingEnd="40dp"/>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_fav"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:textAllCaps = "false"
                    android:text="@string/list_of_favorites"
                    android:onClick="fav_intent"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/medium"
                    android:background="@drawable/back_btn2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingEnd="40dp"/>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <com.akshay.library.CurveBottomBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:bottomBarColor="#FFB601"
                app:curveRadius="53dp"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/White"
                android:id="@+id/cbb"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--menu-->
    <com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingMenuLayout
        android:id="@+id/menulayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:background="@color/White">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgtest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@drawable/back_nav"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="8dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/ghhgkjjjhjl"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:onClick="fehrest_intent"/>
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/content_copy2"/>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="8dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/hghjk"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:onClick="fav_intent"/>
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/heart_icon"
                    android:onClick="fav_intent"/>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="8dp">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/settings2"/>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="8dp">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/gray"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="8dp">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="8dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/jkhjlkjkl"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/content_copy2"/>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="8dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/klkl"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:onClick="finish"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/exit_to_app"/>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingMenuLayout>


</com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingDrawer>
```

Comment: From the error message it looks like you are passing an invalid argument at the point in your code that is specified in the error message. So I'd suggest checking what you pass there and/or putting a breakpoint there and running it through a debugger to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Android Studio to 3.3 ,this solved the problem

Comment: I am using Android studio version 3.6

Comment: Same issue occur in my end, it was fixed now Change the targetSdkVersion in build.gradle.